# Select top 3 values from a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `newscount` in which there are three column `id`, `postid`, `count`. An example of the data is:

```
id | postid | count 
-------------------
2  | 6      | 14 
3  | 8      | 25
4  | 9      | 9
5  | 10     | 16
6  | 11     | 15
```

I want to select 3 `postid`which have maximum count. In the example above it should show 8, 10, 11.

Comment: What if more than one row had a count of 15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` in Descending order with `LIMIT` (to select top 3).

```
SELECT *
FROM newscount
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: that was so simple it did not entered in my mind

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code :

```
SELECT postid FROM newscount ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 3;
```